# when google will bock authorization requests in embedded browsers?

Tags: webview, google-oauth

When google will bock authorization requests in embedded browsers?

It is dated as 20th April 2017. We haven't updated the new changes in our app, will the authorization stop if we continue to use authorization using in embedded browsers?

At the moment it seems to work but we receive the warning "authorization requests in embedded browsers will be blocked on april 20 2017".

Answer (score 1):

We are rolling our the blocking over a few weeks (starting with a very small percent of apps first). So it may still be working for your app but we do advise you to switch now rather than wait.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Authentication is going to stop working.

Google announced on their blog August 22, 2016 [Modernizing OAuth interactions in Native Apps for Better Usability and Security](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html)

On November 1, 2016 they added a notification on our iOS consent page alerting developers of this deprecation. On March 1, 2017 they posted the same notification on the Android consent page and on April 1, they posted the notification for applications retrieving an OAuth token form.

You have had a lot of notice.  That they would begin blocking web-views

> The rollout schedule for the deprecation of web-views for OAuth
>   requests to Google is as follows. Starting October 20, 2016, we will
>   prevent new OAuth clients from using web-views on platforms with a
>   viable alternative, and will phase in user-facing notices for existing
>   OAuth clients. On April 20, 2017, we will start blocking OAuth
>   requests using web-views for all OAuth clients on platforms where
>   viable alternatives exist.

Google has a very large system.  It can take weeks if not months before everything completely dies.   I would change your code now it is going to stop working any day now.