# Google Drive InApp WebView Deprecation Date

Tags: google-oauth

According to the article
https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html

InApp webview authentication request will be blocked from 20th April. But it seems that it is still running for our customers.

Our team is already in process of migration to new SDK . Do we have any tentative dates like when the requests will be actually blocked

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stackoverflow can not tell you when Google will discontinue something Contact Google support.  (Note: Google is a large company it can take months before everything's completely shut down or it could be in an hour. You have had since august to fix your code. )

Comment: Also see:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/43538434/1841839